# file renaming (take 1 part of filename and transfer it to 'beginning' of filename)

Tags: linux, bash

Ok, i have a lot of files which all contain a version number v1 or v2. And i want to match the filenames to other files which are composed as the second file like this:
train.v1_GENENAME_ID.debruijn.txt (this is what i want)

The first file is composed like this:
train.GENENAME_ID_v1.debruijn.txt

And so the v1 should move before the GENENAME. All the version identifiers are the same. Namely v1 or v2

lets say i have a file called: `'train.Glis2_1757.2_v1_deBruijn.txt'` and i want to convert it to this `'train.v1_Glis2_1757.2_deBruijn.txt'`

Is there a easy way to take the v1 from first filename and place it as in the 2nd filename?

I was thinking about combining grep with a if statement. But still not managed to make it work.

Any hints/tips are appreciated.

Comment: According to what kind of pattern is the script supposed to know what to move and where?

Comment: A first step would be to make it an abstract problem, so it is programmable. How can you write it in terms of `XXX.v1_YYY...`? No matter how they are, post your tests so we have an idea.

Comment: @fedorqui i modified the question maybe its more clear now.

Comment: This might be helpful for you.
http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/search/label/rename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one using a for loop and using `sed` to transform the filenames

```
for f in *.txt;
do
    nf=$(echo $f | sed -r 's/([^.]+\.)([^.]+\.)([0-9])_([^_]+)(.*)/\1\4_\2\3\5/')
    echo mv $f $nf
done
```

If you are satisfied with the results you can remove `echo` and let the rename happen

As per your request here is the annotated version explaining how the various parts are extracted and rearranged to fit the desired output

```
echo "train.Glis2_1757.2_v1_deBruijn.txt" | sed -r 
's/([^.]+\.) # match all non-dot characters (+ meaning one or more) followed by a dot and store in group 1 (train.)
   ([^.]+\.) # match all non-dot characters followed by a dot and store in group 2 (Glis2_1757.)
   ([0-9])   # match a single digit and store in group 3 (2)
   _         
   ([^_]+)   # match all non-underscore characters and store in group 4 (v1)
   (.*)      # match all that follow . is a wildcard char in regex and * is for zero or more (_deBruijn.txt)
/\1\4_\2\3\5/' # rearranging the matches to get desired output
```

Comment: Some quotes (`"`) would be nice in order to avoid any surprises.

Comment: @shyam thanks for your answer but my knowledge of regular expressions is to low to completely understand this. Can you please explain some more?

Comment: @shyam thanks for the explanation i just read it. Nice and clear for me now. For the points i will accept your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `rename` distributed with perl:

```
rename 's/(train.)(.*_)(v[0-9].)(deBruijn.txt)/$1$3$2$4/' *
```

On some systems it is called 'ren' or 'pren'.

Comment: Very good one! Just testing - could that expression be used with sed? `echo "train.Glis2_1757.2_v1_deBruijn.txt" | sed 's/(train.)(.*_)(v[0-9].)(deBruijn.txt)/$1$3$2$4/'` does not work to me.

Comment: I think `$1` should be `\1` and you would also require the `-r` flag

Comment: Shouldn't you escape `.`, that is replace it with `\.`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in shell with [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), specifically suffix and prefix removal:

```
FN=train.Glis2_1757.2_v1_deBruijn.txt
STRIPPED=${FN%_deBruijn.txt}                      # "train.Glis2_1757.2_v1"
GENEVERS=${STRIPPED#train.}                       # "Glis2_1757.2_v1"
VERSION=${GENEVERS##*_}                           # "v1"
GENENAME=${GENEVERS%_v[12]}                       # "Glis2_1757.2"

NEWFN=train.${VERSION}_${GENENAME}_deBruijn.txt   # "train.v1_Glis2_1757.2_deBruijn.txt"

mv $FN $NEWFN
```

You don't have to go through all the explicit naming steps above, but I think that's clearer.  Also, this technique could be extrapolated to have arbitrary prefixes (other than "train.") and suffixes (other than "_deBruijn.txt") presuming you can represent them with shell pattern notation.